# Workflow RULES - One rule for multiple nodes

Tags: rules

I would like to create a rule that updates a field (to Yes or No) in two different content types A and B.

In my current rule, when all the fields on content type B are filled up, status field of B is updated to Yes.

I want to update the status field of content type A to Yes as well. (Note: In content type B, there is a node reference to A)

Any ideas will be appreciated. Can this be done using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?